# Formatting text file with awk command

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I am using this command:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1"  "$2}' fort.75 > newfort.75
```

and getting the output as

```
     7  -2.2964292555E+000
     8 -2.3013363831E+000
     9 -2.3071951989E+000
     10 -2.3136811351E+000
     11 -2.3207311925E+000
```

But the desired o/p is

```
      7 -2.2964292555E+000
      8 -2.3013363831E+000
      9 -2.3071951989E+000
     10 -2.3136811351E+000
     11 -2.3207311925E+000
```

The values in the first field should be formatted such that they all have the same width. Also, the second field should start in the same column in each line.

Comment: please add contents of `fort.75` as well to question

Comment: consider using printf

Comment: You did not provide enough information about how the output is to be generated by your `awk` script, e.g. why there is a 7 instead of a 3 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly mean that you would like output in columns (although in your example the data also differs).  If so, try this:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1 "\t" $2}' fort.75 > newfort.75
```

That would separate your output by a TAB character `\t`.

Another possibility is to use `printf` as suggested by Archemar:

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf("%4i %f\n",$1,$2);}' fort.75 > newfort.75
```

where the first column is formatted to (in this case) 4 characters width - adjust as desired. The space is filled up by space " " (no pun intended) and no TAB is used.  The floating point numbers are, however, also reformatted, so please check whether that is OK for you. If not, treat the 2nd column as a string:

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf("%4i %s\n",$1,$2);}' fort.75 > newfort.75
```